# How to filter my search results by location and how to rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently rendering user's search results in my component and those results are being stored in a state called

```
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState<any>([]);
```

However I've added a left navbar that user can search by location, date posted, etc....
I've managed to get the list of cities(location) of the search results on the left navbar, and if user wanted to click each city I wanted to change the search results filtering only by that city.

I so far have been able to get the console.log(location) of each onClick so now I am stuck how I should re render the results. If I update setSearchData with this onClick handle. I get an undefined .map error of other functions in this component.

So.. How am I suppose to handle re-rendering search results based on clicking location filter?

Answer (score 1):

Please try doing this:

```
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState<any>({data: [], save: []}); 

const onChange = (value: string) => {
   setSearchData({
       ...searchData,
       save: searchData.data.filter((x) x.name.indexOf(value) > -1)
   })
}
```

```js
const state = ["Fish","Dog","Cat"]

const data = state.filter((x) => x.indexOf("Fish") > -1)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: This works for one particular city however when I try to add more cities and want to do (AND) instead of (OR) logic, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I've added, you can do this

Comment: Problem with this is... I am able to get the list of locations on the filter NAVBAR by doing this function.. 
const renderLocations = searchData.slice(0, itemsToShow).map((location, i) =>

and when I use your code to setSearchData, it says cannot find map of undefined of .slice etc etc.

Comment: yes, you have to add I just added an answer

Comment: For searching you have to add a new array from useState to store the data, otherwise the data that is in the Data search will be lost

Comment: in here i added useState({data: [], save: []})

Comment: https://repl.it/@JuliusPark1/MonstrousGrouchyCoin#index.js

Comment: problem is.. i am rendering the items by chunkedData[currentPage]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227219/discussion-between-julz-oh-and-kenedi-novriansyah).

Answer (score 0):

Please find a rough code :

```
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState<any>([]); 
filteredData use this to display
const [filterOption , setFilterOption] =useState();
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState<any>([]);

const onFilterChange = () =>{
  setFilterOption()//set filter here
}

useEffect(()=>{
 //... Apply Filter Logic
 let filteredRows = []
 setFilteredData(filteredRows)
```

}, [filterOption])

Comment: So, i added this filter method 
searchData.filter(item => item.city.toLowerCase().includes(location?.toLowerCase()))
but this only works for one city at a time, and if User wanted to keep adding more cities to filter which is basically (this city AND this city AND ).
How can achieve that functionality?

Comment: Could you please paste a code block or link code sandbox with an example?